# Cannot execute script in Termux that requires SU permissions

Tags: android, unix, sh, termux

So I don't usually post, instead spending hours trawling forums looking for an answer - but I'm at a complete loss.

What I want to do:

Quite simple really, I want a script that will automatically change the MAC address on my OnePlus 5, I already have all the commands I need to do this and can easily accomplish it *manually*, getting a script to do it however? Oh boy...

What I have tried:

These are the commands that, when run in termux manually, give me the result I need:

```
ip link set dev wlan0 down

macchanger --random wlan0

ip link set dev wlan0 up
```

Now the reason I don't use ip link set dev wlan0 address xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx is because then I have to enter an address, whereas macchanger can generate this automatically. (I don't have the Unix-foo to generate a MAC address programmatically).

So I did the following, in chronological order:

1) Created a script in nano with these commands.

2) Made the script executable using chmod +x changeMAC.sh

This gives an "Access Denied" error message when executed.

3) Tried first going into SU, then executing the script, this gives a "macchanger" not found error as termux loses the environment when su is invoked. So I installed the tsu wrapper which allows you to call tsu and get su with the environment maintained, equivalent to su --preserve-environment.

However this is where I started banging my head off the desk.

If I do the following in the termux terminal:

```
tsu
./changeMAC.sh
```

The terminal just sits there, doing nothing. If I then type "exit" and hit return I get three "Access Denied" error messages.

I've tried to circumvent the error:

4) Using AutoInput to type into termux like a user but it refused to do so.

5) Executing the shell commands directly from Tasker > Run Shell but I suspect this isn't working because the macchanger package isn't installed in the scope of the tasker shell.

6) Using su --preserve-environment directly, but the same thing happens!

So to summarise my script looks like this:

```
\#!/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/bin/sh

sleep 1

ip link set dev wlan0 down

sleep 1

macchanger --random wlan0

sleep 1

ip link set dev wlan0 up

exit
```

but:

1) Won't work with standard privaleges

2) Doesn't appear to execute when tsu/su --preserve-environment is used, giving errors when the tsu instance is exited out of instead, almost asthough its *waiting* for the instance to end before executing...

3) Works fine when executed manually from a tsu instance.

I think I just do not know enough about the intricacies of Unix/Linux/Android to understand *why* this isn't working and therefore correct it.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Best,

H.

Phone Details:

OnePlus 5, rooted with Magisk

ElementalX Kernel

xXx NoLimits Custom ROM

Edit 1:

I have tried 'sudo' from https://gitlab.com/st42/termux-sudo however this requires su, which then can't find macchanger and I'm back to square one.

Answer (score 1):

#### There is severals reason why it's not working:

- When 'Access Denied', you just simulate an env for the context of your script, if you check /proc/**PID_OF_YOUR_PROCESS**/env you will see an empty env
- If you use chroot solution like [GNURootDebian](https://github.com/corbinlc/GNURootDebian), you will face chroot [jail](http://chroot%20jail)
- Script shell with root permission on android system is wild, expect issue.
- Prefer conditional chaining execution with **'&&' or '||'** over sleep chainning process **'command1;sleep(1);command2;sleep(1)'**

The simpliest solution i can propose you is this:

#### Create a simple Application android, and on your main activity add:

```
protected void      onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    try {
        String[] env = {"PATH=/su/bin:/sbin:/system/sbin:/system/bin:/su/xbin:/system/xbin:/system/xbin/"};
        DataOutputStream outputStream;
        outputStream = new DataOutputStream(Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su", env).getOutputStream());
        outputStream.writeBytes("ip link set dev wlan0 down && macchanger --random wlan0 && ip link set dev wlan0 up && exit \n");
        outputStream.flush();
        Toast.makeText(this, "Macchanger DONE", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Toast.makeText(this, "Macchanger Error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

It work on Nexus 5 Rooter, but you should definetly add a button to control the fonctionnality, and why not print the new mac wich you can find here:

- `cat /sys/class/net/NAME_INTERFACE/address`

And if you want to automate it, same logic, but with [Service](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services) and not [Activity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18517793/whats-the-difference-between-activity-and-service).

Comment: Excellent, I have not written an android application before but this looks like a simple way to start. Thanks for the advice.